# Ajax datatable column adding extra button in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm loading data using ajax datatable but I want to some button edit and details in every row. I have tried but failed. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Here is my cshtml markup where I use a table and data load in Ajax datatable:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Joing Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/Employee/loaddata",
      "type": "GET",
      "datatype": "json"
    },
    "responsive": true,


    "columns": [{
        "data": "FirstName",
        "autoWidth": true
      },
      {
        "data": "LastName",
        "autoWidth": true
      },
      {
        "data": "JoiningDate",
        "autoWidth": true
      }
    ]
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is controller code:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
        private EmployeeContext db = new EmployeeContext();

        public ActionResult loaddata()
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            var clientes = db.Employees.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = clientes }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use the plugin Datatable for JQuery, then you need to purchase a licence for the Editor for the `datatable` here:

https://editor.datatables.net/

Then you need to instantiate a new editor object using `$.fn.dataTable.Editor` and then tell the editor instance which columns need editing at runtime.

Here is an example taken off the Editor sites examples for *[Multi Row editing](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/submitButton)* for setting up the editor itself. Note that the names to need match the column names from the `DataTable` itself and you need to change the `ajax:` setting to point to your `POST` action method.

```
var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: "../php/staff.php",
        table: "#example",
        fields: [ {
                label: "First name:",
                name: "first_name"
            }, {
                label: "Last name:",
                name: "last_name"
            }, {
                label: "Joining Date:",
                name: "JoiningDate"
            }
    } );
```

Then after that you need to define you want to use *Inline Editing*:

```
  // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
    $('#example').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
        editor.inline( this, {
            buttons: { label: '&gt;', fn: function () { this.submit(); } }
        } );
    } );
```

You still need to keep your `DataTable` as well to handle the actual viewing logic.